# how to i search on search results in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, search, laravel, eloquent

There is a simple page where i display search results by keywords.
But now i want to search on those results by some criteria.

How can i do it

SearchController

```
class SearchController extends \BaseController {

    public function search() {
        $keyword = Input::get('header-search-query');

        if (empty($keyword)) {
            $product = Product::paginate(10);
            $this - > setModel($product);
            return View::make('product.listbykeyword') - > with('products', $product);
        }

        return View::make('product.listbykeyword') - > with('products', Product::like('title', $keyword) - > paginate(10));
    }

    public function advance() {
        //what should i put here
    }
}
```

View

```
@foreach($products as $product)
 <div class="media">
    <div class="media-left" style="width:16%;">
        <a href="{{ URL::to('image/'.$product->productImage()->first()['image']) }}">
        {{ HTML::image('image/'.$product->productImage()->first()['image'],'no-image',array('class'=>'media-object','height'=>'100','width'=>'100'))}}
         </a>
     </div>
 <div class="media-body">
     <h4 class="media-heading">{{ HTML::link('/product/'.$product->id,$product->title) }}</h4>
     <p>{{substr($product->description,0,85)}}</p>
     <p>Price : {{$product->price}} TK</p>
     <p class="time">{{$product->created_at->diffForHumans()}}
          <b>Near</b> {{$product->location}}
     </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <hr></hr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Use you need to search the results that is got from the view ? then why not you use [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net)

Comment: yes i want to do something like data table.But not as like as datatable.

Comment: if you go to this link http://noneedjob.com/project/public/search you will get a idea what i want to do

Comment: **MethodNotAllowedHttpException**

Comment: In the datatable you can have filter, search, pagination , then why not datatables ? You wanted to know how to do that in laravel or what ?

Comment: datatable is a good idea.i have already used it.i want to know how datatable retrieve information where anything is typed on the search field.
sorry for the link.Go to this link http://noneedjob.com/project/public and press the search icon to the top beside the "all category"

Comment: Yes, i got it, then for this type of UI you shall have some ajax search result . You can place a textbox over the result and call the ajax which will return you the result in the keychange event

Comment: Thanks Sulthan Allaudeen this is really helpful.If you provide me some example that it will be more helpful.

Comment: Ok, i am writing you the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was true that you can't able to use [Datatables](https://www.datatables.net/) in your case as it is a public search i would recommend you to use ajax call on the keychange event.

**Step 1 :**

Detect the keychange from your textbox

```
<input id='myTextbox1' type='text'/>
$('#myTextbox1').on('input', function() {
    alert('Text1 changed!');
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bSX6/)

**Step 2 :**

Call the ajax page to your controller

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "yourcontroller",
        data : dataString,
        success : function(data){
        $("#result").html(data);                           
        }
  });
```

Place a div named as `result` in your page.

So, First time you will get the result from your default controller you use to search and then next time whenever you type the text in your `myTextbox1` it will call the controller `yourcontroller` and in your controller you should get the `datastring` and return the matching output to the view.

Hope this helps you.